# Preemption among SOFTIRQ context

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

I have a system which has following config;

- SMP platform(but I am only concerning local CPU) and Preemption off
- ISR A -> raise_softirq(1)
- ISR B -> raise_softirq(2)

When SOFTIRQ 1 is running, Interrupt B comes and then ISR B kicked in.
When irq_exit() happens at ISR B, it will invoke softirq. So, it will schedule SOFTIRQ 2 (without taking care of SOFTIRQ 1 which was interrupted).

Is it right statement?

Another question. At this moment, if SOFTIRQ 1 disabled "bottom_half", where we dectect bottom half is disabled and skipped SOFTIRQ 2's execution?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you have confused between SOFTIRQ and HARDIRQ.   Softirq in Linux kernel is the "bottom_half" in IRQ processing, which is **scheduled** by the task scheduler for execution to handle delayed IRQ processing.   And during this processing, it can potentially handle multiple delay IRQ processing, say IRQ A and IRQ B in your case.

But if any IRQ enters into the system, it will trigger the ISR handler, and there is no immediately triggering of any SOFTIRQ, **only being scheduled for later processing**, not "invoke" as your wording says.   (ie, all hardware IRQ handler are not supposed to call raise_softirq(), but schedule a handler for IRQ processing)

So in summary, for your scenario:

After ISR B have ended, it may submit SOFTIRQ B for later processing - **but it is NOT calling raise_softirq()**.   But since SOFTIRQ A have been intercepted half-way, after any hardware interrupt it will continue the last tasks before, and so SOFTIRQ A will execute to completion.

To elaborate on raise_softirq() internal, which call raise_softirq_irqoff():

```
inline void raise_softirq_irqoff(unsigned int nr)
{
        __raise_softirq_irqoff(nr);

        /*
         * If we're in an interrupt or softirq, we're done
         * (this also catches softirq-disabled code). We will
         * actually run the softirq once we return from
         * the irq or softirq.
         *
         * Otherwise we wake up ksoftirqd to make sure we
         * schedule the softirq soon.
         */ 
        if (!in_interrupt())
                wakeup_softirqd();
}
```

As the comment goes, if you are inside softirq A and IRQ B comes in, IRQ B processing will end - to be re-run after it finishes the current SOFTIRQ A.

To emphasize that all hardware does not call "raise_softirq()", a search of linux kernel yield the following result (none is from hardware, which is from the "drivers" branch):

[image]

And in the networking IRQ handler - the napi_schedule() is called.   (In general search for "sched" inside all drivers IRQ handler).   The following is from drivers/net/usb/r8152.c:

[image]